# Disable or remove NewsToday2

Tags: macos, applications

How can I get rid of NewsToday2 process? I tried deleting it but it seems to be protected, even with super user it did not work.
Deletion seems to be hard, but maybe there is some way to disable it entirely?

Tried corrupting some of its files, did not work.

[image]

It is ridiculous apple adds such a battery draining app, with no option to disable.

Comment: How do you know it is Apple. I do not have it on my mac Mini M1 running Ventura. So we need toi know more about this proicess

Comment: I found that it's the news widget running in the Notification Center. I would assume that you can remove it from the Notification Center, that should stop the process.

Comment: @ErniePC12 seems like it was that. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to have helped "System Preferences" -> "Notifications"

[image]

Comment: I propose making this post a community wiki. It is based on a comment, and therefore, the poster is not the one that came with the answer and should not receive any credit for it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not help

Comment: that disable notification we ask for a NewsToday2 demon that use 100% CPU every few days to stop loading